# What is a boundary condition for capacitors/dielectrics?

Tags: electricity, terminology, electric-fields, capacitance, boundary-conditions

I am extremely confused about what boundary conditions are. One minute ago I was solving easy capacitor questions and the next minute I am being asked boundary condition questions and there is no such section in my textbook on boundary condition. I have some questions below if you could please explain from scratch/beginner level what boundary condition is and what the goal is.

I have some questions below you could use to explain what these conditions are… I have looked all over google and search various videos and I still cant find any information on them.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: The images don't say anything about boundary conditions. Could you be more specific about what you are being asked, and especially what you don't understand about it?

Comment: those are questions, images are figures of the question. I dont know what boundary conditions are and how they are used to find the electric field at different regions with dielectrics

Comment: Someone may post an explanation here, but I really think your best bet is to find a textbook or other resource that explains what boundary conditions are. You may need to look in a textbook on differential equations, because that's really where the idea of boundary conditions comes from.